# Holomorphic functions on a region.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ be a region in complex plane $\Bbb C$, $f\colon A\to f(A)$  is continuous on $A$. $f^n$ is holomorphic on $A$. How to prove that $f$ is holomorphic on $A$?

Partial proof.
I have proved the theorem when $0$ doesn't belong to $A$. (by composition of functions)

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? What are the condition about it?

Comment: The problem should be easier in the case when $0 \not \in f(A)$, rather than $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f^n$ is holomorphic in $A$, it is either identically $0$ or its zeros are isolated.  As an isolated singularity of $f$, an isolated zero is removable.